# Python AttributeError: 'QCheckBox' object has no attribute 'ischecked'

Tags: python, dictionary, attributeerror

I've created a minimal reproducible example for my issue. I don't understand why it's showing `AttributeError: 'QCheckBox' object has no attribute 'ischecked'` Can somebody please help me understand the issue and any solution.

Example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class a:
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.checkboxes_items = {
            'this': False,
            'that': True
        }
        
    def checkboxes(self):
        self.checkboxes_items_list = []
        for item, val in self.checkboxes_items.items():
            chkbox = QCheckBox()
            chkbox.setText(item)
            chkbox.setChecked(val)
            self.checkboxes_items_list.append(chkbox)  # Add to list
        for x in self.checkboxes_items_list:
            print(x.ischecked())                    # This line causes the issue


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    class_inst = a()
    class_inst.checkboxes()
    app.exec()
```

Note: I've tried to use `self.chkbox` instead of `chkbox`. but no help.

Comment: Try *chkbox.is**C**heched()*.

Comment: Capitalize the C `.isChecked()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [[Qt.Doc]: List of All Members for QCheckBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcheckbox-members.html), the method (inherited from *QAbstractButton*) name is *is**C**hecked* (1<sup>st</sup> *C* capitalized), so the line should be:

```py
print(x.isChecked())
```

Comment: Holy crap ‍♂️ Dumb me, That was my mistake, This is ridiculous, I wasted a lot of time figuring out why it wasn't working. Silly mistake of mine. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do not worry. It happens to everyone.